# Account specific interface binding

Tags: linux, networking, user-accounts

Im looking to have applications started from different accounts automatically bind to a specific interface. for example: applications started on accountA bind to eth0 and applications started from accountB bind to eth1. Hope what I am looking for is clear.

Comment: I answered that under http://superuser.com/questions/360934/automatically-binding-applications-to-a-network-interface-based-on-the-account-t